# Finding the gradient of the tangent to a parabola

Tags: calculus

how to use the quadratic theory to find the gradient of the tangent to:
y=x^2 at the point (2,4).

how to go about solving this simple problem as I am mixed up.

Thank you.

Comment: "Quadratic theory"?? What's that, anyway?  And by "gradient of the tangent" (?) you, apparently, want the slope of the tangent line to that function at the given point...right?

Comment: i do want the slope of the tangent line to the function at the given point you are right

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

(1) The slope to the tangent line to the graph 0f $\;f(x)\;$ at a point $\;(a, f(a)\;$ on 
the graph is given, assuming $\;f\;$ is differentiable at that point, by $\;f'(a)\;$

(2) For **any** $\;n\in\Bbb R\;$, we have that $\;(x^n)'=nx^{n-1}\;$

Comment: this is solving it using differentiation i want to solve it using pre-calc (algebric way)

Comment: Your original tags are "calculus" and "algebra-precalculus"

Answer (score 1):

Note that in modern analysis one usually *defines* the line tangent to $f$ in $x_0$ as $$y=f'(x_0)(x-x_0)+f(x_0).$$
So, for the sake of rigour, you should prove that the result obtained with less advanced instruments is equivalent. However, let's *define* the tangent line as the one which is not vertical and intersects the parabola in one and only one point, $(x_0,ax_0^2)$. We have two equations for the tangent: $$y=m(x-x_0)+ax_0^2,$$
that is, the line passes through $(x_0,ax_0^2)$. The second one is obtained by considering the quadratic equation $$ax^2=m(x-x_0)+ax_0^2,$$
which is satisfied in the intersections of the parabola and the line. The second contraint is given by the condition $\Delta(m)=0$, where $\Delta$ is the discriminant of this quadratic (and it depends on the parameter $m$, having fixed $a$).

Comment: That's a new perspective for me!

Comment: Student, Is this the derivation you were looking for? @TonyK I read somewhere that Descartès calculated the tangent line to the parabola $y=ax^2$ in a way similar to this. I don't have the reference, though.

Answer (score 0):

The equation of a line is $f(x)=mx+b$ where $m$ is the slope.
The equation of a tangent line to a function $f(x)$ on $a$ is $f(x)=f'(a) (x-a) + f(a) = f'(a)\ x+[f'(a)\ a+f(a)]$, which has the form $y=mx+b$. The slope is $f'(a)$

$$f'(x)=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)=2x$$

You have $a=2$, becuase the point is $(a,f(a))=(2,4)$

So, the slope $m$ is $$m=f'(a)=f'(2)=2(2)=4$$

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you ask for the gradient of a tangent to a curve, you are getting into the territory of calculus. But don't worry, it's not too hard.

We start by finding the gradient of a line through the two points $A$ and $B$, where $A=(2,4)$ and $B$ is any nearby point on the curve. So take some small number $h \ne 0$, let $x_B = 2 + h$, and put $y_B = x^2 = (2+h)^2$. Now we have a point $B=(x_B,y_B)$ that is on the curve, and close to the point $A=(2,4)$. (Here you might like to draw yourself a picture.)

Now we calculate the gradient of the line through $A$ and $B$: this is just
$$(y_B-y_A)/(x_B-x_A) = ((2+h)^2-4)/((2+h)-2) = (h^2+4h)/h = h + 4$$

Now you can see that as the point $B$ gets closer and closer to $A$ (or in other words, as $h$ gets closer and closer to $0$), this gradient gets closer and closer to $4$. In fact we can make it as close to $4$ as we like by making $h$ small enough.

So the gradient of the curve at $A$ is $4$. And that's calculus!